# Translation in Symfony 4 using po/mo files (with plural)

Tags: symfony, translation, gettext

I have to deal with translation in po/mo format.

Basically an example of my po:

```
msgid "content_book"
msgid_plural "content_books"
msgstr[0] "%s book"
msgstr[1] "%s books"
```

It seems that `%s` or `%d` placeholders are quite common.

But the Symfony component use the placeholder `%count%`
https://github.com/symfony/translation-contracts/blob/main/TranslatorTrait.php#L50

Is there any possibility to use `Symnfony/Translation` component with po/mo file without to convert them in the icu format (https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/translation/message_format.html)?

I have to use sf 4.4 for now (wait for the next lts in 5.x).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post the PHP source code that the po file was generated from here. And please make sure that the strings contain the `%count%` placeholder and work for your base language (English). Most probably it will *not* work because translatable strings have to be constant. If the string is already interpolated before it is passed to a gettext function, the translation cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Gettext is not meant to be used in the way you are attempting to use it. `msgid` (and `msgid_plural`) are supposed to contain the actual human-readable text in English (or whatever your base language is), not some symbol names.

PO files with only symbol names as `msgid`s are also painful to translate, and involve much more manual work than proper PO files do.